# Interpreting a confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I have a binary classification problem.

The accuracy score is 52%

The precision for 0 is 53% and the precision for 1 is 49%

When using `predict_proba()` does this mean my model more accurately predicts when the outcome should be classified zero as opposed to one?

I'm not sure if this is telling me that I should be using the the first value `(ynew[0][0])` returned from `predict_proba()` as opposed to the second `(ynew[0][1])`.

Here is the entire confusion matrix:

[image]

Comment: one can compare both values and decide on largest proba